# How to use searchbox in html?

Tags: html

I have created an api which will search the data from my database. 
It works like this:  localhost://12345/api/example/search/userinput.  I want to integrate this in my frontend, so to do that i have written the following code in my html file

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search TradeId" name="input">
<button onclick="document.location = 'api/example/search/input'" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" >Search Trade</button>
```

But what it is doing is searching the "input" in my database, not the values i have entered.
Lets say i have to search john but instead it is searching input.

Comment: Can you provide additional details here? How does the api work? How does it find the value from input? I can see you are not passing anything to the API. May be query params are need? `api/example/search/input?find=' + document.getElementById('input').value`. It remains unclear what error you are getting or how your back end works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve by writing script

```
<script>
        function myFunction(){
            var x = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
            var q = location.href;
            var y = "api/example/search/";
            var t = q+y+x;
            location.assign(t);
        }
</script>

<input type="search" placeholder="Search TradeId" id="myinput">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" >Search Trade</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```html
<button onclick="document.location = 'api/example/search/input?' + document.getElementById('input').value" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" >Search Trade</button>
```

But is your API enpoint '/input' or '/userinput'?